# Why doesn't the system free the memory of C and Rust programs properly? But C++ programs seem to have no issues

Tags: c++, c, rust, memory, memory-leaks

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread_function(void *arg) {
    char **records = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(char *));
    if (records == NULL) {
        perror("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        records[i] = malloc(16);
        if (records[i] == NULL) {
            perror("Memory allocation failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        sprintf(records[i], "%d", i);
    }

    printf("done\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        free(records[i]);
    }
    free(records);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[400];

    for (int i = 0; i < 400; ++i) {
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_function, NULL) != 0) {
            perror("Thread creation failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 400; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    while (1) {
      sched_yield();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```rust
fn main() {
    for _ in 0..400 {
        std::thread::spawn(|| {
            let mut records: Box<Vec<String>> = Box::default();
            for i in 0..1_000_000 {
                let record = i.to_string();
                records.push(record);
            }
            println!("done");
        });
    }

    loop {
        std::thread::yield_now();
    }
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1600; ++i) {
    std::thread([=]() {
      std::vector<std::string> records;
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        std::string record = std::to_string(i);
        records.push_back(record);
      }
      std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    }).detach();
  }

  while (true) {
    std::this_thread::yield();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I use `top` (and the built-in monitor on Mac) to check the memory usage of my programs. When the logic in C and Rust programs reaches a code block with the infinite loop, the memory is not properly reclaimed, and there's still a significant amount of memory in use, often several hundred megabytes.

However, with C++ programs, the memory usage remains low, usually just a few megabytes.

I've been investigating this issue for a few days, and my speculation includes the possibility of memory fragmentation, or perhaps excessive memory deallocation. It could also be related to allocator caching (considering there's some overhead in calling system interfaces to allocate memory). However, I haven't found a convincing answer yet.

Given my limited experience in system programming, is there some key knowledge I might be lacking? Could you shed some light on this for me?

Only when the thread count is sufficiently high (ideally, just below the threshold for being killed) does it trigger improper memory release. This is another significant puzzle for me. If the thread count is low, this issue doesn't arise. If you attempt to replicate this locally, it's advisable to experiment with adjusting the thread count.

Comment: Your assumption that `free` (or vector destructor) is supposed to return memory to system is simply wrong.

Comment: The language runtime often keeps free'd memory around, expecting it to be needed again soon for new allocations.

Comment: However, even after waiting for a considerable amount of time, the memory doesn't seem to be returned. There should be some mechanism for returning memory to the system, right?

Comment: No, there is no sch mechanism, unless you use the system API to allocate the memory directly from the OS. Of course in C every allocator implementation is also free to provide such a mechanism. Same for implementors of Rusts `Allocator` trait.

Comment: @xhwhis "There should be some mechanism for returning memory to the system". That would require a language runtime and some sort of garbage collection. Your system allocator has to decide what to do with `free`d memory immediately. And most of the time it won't release it back to the kernel on the assumption that it will be needed later (and thus it won't have to ask kernel for new memory).

Comment: There is also an OS component. Don't know about Mac, but on Windows it is known that - even if you do return memory to the OS - it will not bother to reclaim those pages until they are needed for something else.

Comment: *"There should be some mechanism for returning memory to the system, right?"* Yes, you can write your own (de)allocation functions and return memory to system.

Answer (score 10):

Modern c++ standard library implementations generally use a small string optimisation where the characters are stored within the string structure until the string reaches a certain size (something like 20+ characters on a 64-bit system). As all your strings are small they never use separate heap allocations. Each thread therefore only allocates the vector memory on the heap in a single block (though a second one will be created temporarily as the vector grows).

Rust doesn't seem to have any SSO so both your rust and c implementations do a separate heap allocation for each string in addition to the allocation for the container. This leads to both increased memory usage and a more fragmented heap increasing the apparent memory usage in the OS.

None of your programs have a genuine memory leak though, if you keep running them indefinitely I'd imagine they'd all stabilise to a set memory usage (assuming the number of threads running at any one time doesn't increase).

Rust's [compact_str](https://docs.rs/compact_str/latest/compact_str/) should make your rust implementation behave more like your c++ one.